# Object invisible in material/solid preview modes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am having an issue where my object is invisible everywhere EXCEPT in render mode or when rendered. It's strange because it sometimes shows up in a weird sort of transparent manner, sometimes not at all. Also invisible in Eevee mode which is annoying because I use that to quickly make adjustments as opposed to Cycles. See screenshot - the box is the object in question. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you kindly share your Eevee material settings from the material tab after switching to Eevee to render? Since the material preview can only be modified in detail after converting to Eevee renderer to fix the material preview and then switch back to cycles again. My first guess would be that you have _Alpha Hashed_ or _Alpha Clip_ in your Eevee material settings.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I added it to the post, lmk, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Blend Mode` to **Opaque** under materials properties. you might have accidentally changed it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Harry, this has been puzzling me for ages!

Comment: no problem always happy to help :)